# A better way to phrase "his masterwork" or "his epic"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

In the context of an artist. Like, let's say, Dali's "melting clocks" painting; we would call that his (blank), AKA his most recognizable/meaningful/popular/"epic" work.

I think there is, perhaps, a French/Latin term Americans use? I'm not sure...

Comment: Are you looking for 'his *Magnum Opus?'*

Comment: Certainly one to watch.

Comment: @Autoresponder, could you post your answer, so we can upvote it?

Comment: You really shouldn’t use *epic* to mean ‘popular’, ‘big’ or even merely ‘great’.  It has a specific sense related to narrative poetry, and if you to dilute it to mean those other things, there is nothing left to take on its unique job.

Comment: @tchrist While that is true - surely you are aware of the consumption and re-definition of the term "epic" by the slang-spitting youth. It's common in video game tournaments, etc., for things to be described as "epic" that, in actuality, are not.

Comment: @Autoresponder Yes - that's the one I was looking for!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my mind, **magnum opus** stands far above the rest as the term one would use in this context.

Comment: Note that the form *opus magnum* is occasionally seen, and means the same thing.  The singular seems to use the version with the adjective first quite a bit more often than those with the noun first. However, when cast into the plural, *opera magna* and *magna opera* occur with comparable frequency.

Answer (score 5):

Dalí’s [*Persistence of Memory*](http://www.edali.org/persistence-of-memory.jsp) is considered to be his *[signature](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/signature?q=signature)* work; it’s the painting that people most commonly associate with him.

Here, *signature* is used in this sense:

> a distinctive pattern, product, or characteristic by which someone or
>   something can be identified

Comment: +1 never thought of this - very good response. Magnum opus was the one I was reaching for in the far recesses of my own brain, but this is great, too.

Answer (score 4):

In musical contexts, a “most recognizable work” often is called a  *[signature tune](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/signature+tune)*.  For example, [Benny Goodman's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benny_Goodman) signature tune, or *theme song*, was *Let's Dance*, “based on *Invitation to the Dance* by Carl Maria von Weber”;   [Louis Armstrong's](http://www.pbs.org/jazz/biography/artist_id_armstrong_louis.htm) was *When It's Sleepytime Down South*; Tommy Dorsey's was *I'm Getting Sentimental Over You* (as shown in [bigbandlibrary's](http://www.bigbandlibrary.com/themesongs.html) themesongs list).

Answer (score 3):

That would be Dali's [pièce de résistance](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pi%C3%A8ce+de+r%C3%A9sistance?q=piece%20de%20resistance):

> *(especially with reference to creative work)* the most important or remarkable feature:

Wiktionary's [definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pi%C3%A8ce_de_r%C3%A9sistance) reads:

> *(idiomatic)* A **masterpiece**; the most memorable accomplishment of one’s career or lifetime.

The thesaurus has [more suggestions](http://thesaurus.com/browse/masterpiece) including the *magnum opus* suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The French term *[chef-d’œuvre](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/chef-d%27%C5%93uvre?q=chef-d%27oeuvre)* is regularly used in English to mean *masterpiece*. Its literal translation is *chief* or *principal work*.

Comment: +1 for principal work - never thought of that term. I would use the French term described, but "œ" is not so manageable on my English keyboard.

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade I actually typed "oe" and the site elided them. In standard typography separate letters are more often used.

Answer (score 1):

Here, [*masterpiece*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/masterpiece) is an appropriate word.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say either his *masterpiece* or his *magnum opus*.